# Android: how to hide ActionBar on certain activities

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I've developed a simple demo application with a splash screen a map and some regular screens.

I have an action bar at the top that contains a logo. It all looks fine on my phone (Galaxy s1 I9000 V2.3) but when i test it on Galaxy s2 v4 the action bar appears also in the splash screen and in the map screen.

The spalsh and map activity are not even inheriting from ActionBarActivity so how is that possible and how can i make it go away?

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/android_logo"
            android:label=""
            android:logo="@drawable/android_logo" >

            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PackageActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/android_logo"
            android:label=""
            android:logo="@drawable/android_logo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

MapActivity definition (it's a long one so i included just the definition):

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
```

Splash Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

    private static final long SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Apply the following in your Theme for the Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I can't use `getActionBar` as the activity is not inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: if i use `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` wouldn't that hide it on all screens?

Comment: Update my answer which should be more suitable for your need.

Answer (score 170):

As you are asking about how to **hide** in a **certain activity**, this is what you need :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 44):

1.Go to your `manifest.xml` file.

2.`Find` the `activity tag` for which you want to hide your ActionBar and then `add` ,

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

```
           <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            >
```

Answer (score 31):

If you want to get full screen without actionBar and Title.

Add it in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and use the style at activity of manifest.xml.

```
<activity ....
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" > ......
</activity>
```

Answer (score 18):

The `ActionBar` usually exists along `Fragments` so from the `Activity` you can hide it

```
getActionBar().hide();
getActionBar().show();
```

and from the `Fragment` you can do it

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
getActivity().getActionBar().show();
```

Comment: I use : `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

in ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 9):

This works for me! Put this in your Activity in manifests

```
<activity
   // ...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
   // ...
   </activity>
```

You can also make your custom theme in styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        // more custom...
    </style>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 9):

To hide the ActionBar add this code into java file.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you were using Theme.AppCompat.Light, a better equivalent would be Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

I found that using Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar caused my button text to be invisible so I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Low Profile mode
[See here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html)

Just search for `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` that also dims the navigation buttons if they are present of screen.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to this :), i'll check @SiKni8 solution first as i prefer non coding solution

Comment: No problem, I found it really useful for displaying a full screen map in my app, works really well for me.

Answer (score 5):

Apply the following in your Theme for the Activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then Apply the following in your Style in style.xml

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: ".NoActionBar" save my time thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers would help with the ActionBar thing. To add to it, use the following code in case you are using the Splash Screen:
Use this before you set the content view:

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Just to clarify, here's how you do it:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This would make your screen a full screen, i.e remove the top bar where you see the network bar, etc

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For selectively hiding Actionbar in activities:

Add the following code to onCreate (preferably on the last line of the function)

Kotlin:

`supportActionBar?.hide()`

Java:

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: why last line , I use on first line , is any problem?

Answer (score 1):

This works in API 27

In the styles.xml replace code to the following....

```
<resources>
    <!-- No Action Bar -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in the files (eg. activity_list.xml) in which you do want to have a toolbar put the following code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

If you have problems switch to linear layout (because that is what this code is tested on)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up):

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar. However, app bar features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over various Android releases. As a result, **the native ActionBar behaves differently depending on what version of the Android system a device may be using**. By contrast, the most recent features are added to the support library's version of **Toolbar**, and they are available on any device that can use the support library.

So one option is to disable ActionBar completely (in the app manifest.xml file) and then add Toolbar in every page that needs an ActionBar.

(follow the above link for step-by-step explanation)

Answer (score 1):

Add New Style in your style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and then add following line in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you activity extends **AppCompatActivity** then you can add this line
**super.getSupportActionBar().hide();** before **setContentView()**

Answer (score 1):

**getsupportactionbar.hide();**

100% it's will work any version android studio based on java language.

Answer (score 0):

Replace AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for padding attribute if the issue still exists after changing theme.

Padding Issue creating a white space on top of fragment window / app window

[image: Padding Issue creating a white space on top of fragment window / app window]

Once you remove the padding - top value automatically the white space is removed.

Answer (score 0):

First cheek MainActivity for activity tag,Like -

> public class MainActivity extends **AppCompatActivity**

Then goto menifest xml file and write-

> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

in activity tag