# how to remove the title of my activity when I add a button navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a new button navigation activity in the option New> Activity> Button Navigation Activity. But I want to hide the header of the activity that always appears at the top left. How can I make this change?
[image]

Comment: I think you meant "bottom" navigation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`this.getSupportActionBar().hide();`

To hide entire **ActionBar**

Or you can try this ON YOUR activity

`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

It will hide your text only

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fragment and the action bar is the default you can call this with empty String

```
//Kotlin
requireActivity().actionBar.title = ""
//Java
requireActivity().getActionBar.setTitle("")
```

If its Activity

```
//Kotlin
actionBar.title = ""
//Java
getActionBar.setTitle("")
```

If you have your own toolbar you can set the title with an empty String.

N/B you can set null or empty string. Should work fine.

Assuming that you want to hide the ActionBar you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545450/11888547)

Answer (score 0):

Extend your app theme from `NoActionBar` theme like the following

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Else if you want to hide title bar not in whole app, but in specific Activity then create a `NoActionBar` theme separately

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

and then in manifest

`<activity android:name=".yourpackage.subpack.YourActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />`